# How to use same Custom Layout with different Image and Text in android Preference class

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to insert custom layout in android Preference class. My custom layout contains one ImageView and one TextView. There are 7 preferences and all preferences have same custom layout but different images and texts. Now one way to implement such Preference Screen is, make 7 .xml files one for each preference. Is there any other way so that I need to make only one .xml file and I can set image source and text string programatically ?

**EDIT : I need to show all 7 preferences simultaneously. **

Answer (score 0):

You can use same layout and changing then at runtime.
For example,

```
TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv1.setText("tv1");
layout.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv1.setText("tv2");
layout.addView(tv2);
.
.
TextView tv5 = findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv1.setText("tv5");
layout.addView(tv5);
```

Or you can just change their data at runtime by using only single reference to use same layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one layout with all your views for all preferences, but you need to control them at run time by using:

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
thirdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
fourthView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
. . .
```

Comment: i need to all 7 preferences simultaneously.

Comment: Why is the need to load 7 preferences at one time? Can you please be more specific? Did you mean you are loading 7 preference values at one time or 7 layouts at once?

Comment: 7 preference values at one time.

Comment: Can you please post your preference class?

Comment: preference class ?? Its an xml attribute. Basically I am designing setting activity for my app.

Comment: <Preference 
     android:layout="@layout/layout1"/>
<Preference 
android:layout="@layout/layout2"> and so on....

Comment: Yes, your settings activity, please edit your question and add post activity

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I edit in my question. I am new at StackOverflow .

Comment: From my side I have given all information in question.